# Use up the store credit

Tags: mac-appstore, apple-id, itunes-store

I have 0.80$ credit and I need to use it in order to change my region, so I can buy more store credit, since my credit card is not from USA anymore I moved back

I need to find a way to use that amount, do you know any apps? how do I find an app in price order?

Answer (score 0):

Since the Apple App Store has standardized price points ($0.99, $1.99, etc), you won't find an app that is $0.80 unfortunately.

There isn't any way to search by price in the app store, but services such as [AppAdvice.com](http://appadvice.com/apps/price-changes) and others can help a bit.

My recommendation is that you choose an app that you want, figure out the price, including tax. Ask a friend in the US to purchase an App Store gift card via the App Store app, in the amount that is the difference between your app of choice, inlcuding tax, less your $0.80. This friend will email you the gift code, which will load into your gift card balance. Purchase your app, and you have zero balance.

Perhaps even easier: purchase an $0.80 gift certificate for a friend in the US, and email it to them.

Answer (score 0):

The normal procedure is to add a valid billing source and buy something that uses all the credit and then do the switch.

If for whatever reason, you can't add a valid credit/debit card for your current region, then asking for help from iTunes store support is the best bet.

- https://www.apple.com/support/itunes/contact/

You could even ask them if there is a donate to charity option so you felt better about spending some extra $$ to get your balance to zero and thus eligible to make whatever change you want to your purchases going forward.